# Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference error in bootstrap typeahead only in IE

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have a webform application that utilizes `bootstrap3-typeahead.js`, and I've also included `<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>` in the `.aspx` page where I use typeahead.

The typeahead itself is working fine EXCEPT the error message on the property used in `bootstrap3-typeahead.js` and I get it only in IE (IE11).

I've read many QA articles on similar error messages and tried moving around the position of `<script>` but it did nothing.  but I can't find the solution at all. What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT (solved my case but ...)

I had the `<script>` tag for `bootstrap3-typeahead.js` in the Site.Master as well, and the error message disappeared after removing the tag. There might have been a conflict because I had it both in `Site.Master` and the `.aspx` page?

It solved my case but I can't explain why it solved, so if someone could explain that'll be great.

Answer (score 1):

My code:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Reporting:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference

And solve by changing to:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The package I'm to use depends on the full package of JQuery, and if I use only the min package, it failed to find the symbol.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: I was also using a master page and had the bootstrap js in the master. It was solved by moving the bootstrap js script tag to the aspx page.  the problem started after I added a global.asax file. In my opinion it is related to a load delay of the header in the master.

Answer (score 0):

follow steps below...

- jQuery must come first
- then Popper.js
- and then bootstrap

thats fix my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/understrap/understrap/issues/449#issuecomment-373323099